# Formatear Fecha en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, carbon

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mi modelo

```
public static function traerVacantes(){
    $vacantes = Vacante::join("empresas", "vacantes.empresa_id", "=", "empresas.id")
                 ->join("cargos", "vacantes.cargo_id", "=", "cargos.id")
                 ->join("sucursales", "vacantes.sucursal_id", "=", "sucursales.id")
                 ->join("comunas", "sucursales.comuna_id", "=", "comunas.id")
                 ->join("regiones", "comunas.region_id", "=", "regiones.id")
                 ->select("vacantes.descripcion as descripcion", "vacantes.created_at as fecha_creado", 
                        "vacantes.fecha_fin as fecha_fin", "vacantes.estado as estado", "vacantes.codigo as codigo", 
                        "empresas.nombre as empresa", "cargos.nombre as cargo", "sucursales.direccion as sucursal", 
                        "comunas.nombre as comuna", "regiones.nombre as region");

      return $vacantes;

}
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es saber como puedo formatear el campo created_at para que me aparezca así 07-05-2019...

he probado con los mutadores que se configuran en el modelo pero no he conseguido el resultado que necesito.

desde ya les agradezco su tiempo, saludos.

Comment: Por favorito agrega como has configurado el protected cata en el modelo

Comment: esta de la siguiente manera:   protected $table = "vacantes";

    protected $fillable = [

       'id', 'empresa_id', 'sucursal_id', 'cargo_id', 'descripcion', 'codigo', 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_fin', 'estado', 'created_at'
   ];

Comment: ¿La idea es formatearlo solo para mostrarlo en una vista?

Comment: Exacto, lo estoy mostrando en un <card> donde listo todos los datos de la tabla vacantes.

Comment: @Rafa te recomiendo que re formatees la pregunta, ya que preguntaste algo primero, ahora pides otra cosa, tomate tu tiempo formulado y lo necesario para que esta pregunta sea aceptada por la comunidad. Saludos.

Comment: elimino esta pregunta entonces???

Comment: @Rafa lo correcto sería dejar esta pregunta como estaba inicialmente, y si tienes problemas con Vue, formula otra pregunta exponiendo el nuevo inconveniente.

Comment: ok, eso es lo que haré entonces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que dicho campo (timestamp) es una instancia de Carbon, tan solo debes aplicar el método format() con la sintaxis respectiva:

```
{{ $vacante->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}
```

Por si acaso, acá está la documentación respectiva de Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

Comment: Entiendo, pero qué pasa si esa respuesta que obtengo de la consulta la estoy iterando con un v-for en vue?...

Comment: Eso es un problema distinto al planteado en la pregunta.

Comment: la idea es enviar la fecha ya formateada a vue

Comment: El título de la pregunta dice "Formatear fecha en Laravel", y eso lo resuelve mi respuesta.

Comment: He editado la pregunta